# Installation folder for Microsemi LiberoSoC_V11_8_SP2_Lin.tar.gz

Tags: installation, fpga

I'm trying to install the LiberoSoC development toolchain for FPGA programming from this [link](https://www.microsemi.com/products/fpga-soc/design-resources/design-software/libero-soc#downloads). My Operating system is Elementary OS version 0.3.2.

The installation process asks me to run the install program in the same level as "adm, bin, data, etc". The error screenshot is shown below:
[image: Installation error message]

I have tried to install the program in the following directories and have received the same error message:

1. /usr/local/
2. /usr/share/
3. /usr/bin
4. ~/usr
5. ~
6. /opt/

I have also attached the README file below which shows the installation instructions:

[image: README file]

Answer (score 1):

As the readme and the microsemi download page tell you, this is only a patch that needs to be applied to a previously installed version of Libero SoC, specifically 11.8 or 11.8 SP1.

If you already have it installed, install the patch to the folder where Libero SoC 11.8 is installed. Otherwise, get a proper installation rather than just the serivce pack patch.

Comment: Hi, true but I'm getting the exact same error with Libero SoC 11.8 and SP1

Comment: try downloading Libero SoC 11.8, not one of the service packs and running the setup as root. If that does not work, post the error message you get then...

Comment: Yes what DLnd said is correct - this is Microsemi standard practise.   Any patches does depends on the proper installation of the non-patch version.   The "adm, bin, data" message is just to make sure you are doing the installation of the patch at the same directory as the original installation.